# What is the complementary map of a serial concatenation of quantum channels?

Tags: quantum-operation, noise, channel-capacity

I have been studying serial concatenations of quantum channels, i.e. $\mathcal{N}_{A\rightarrow B}=\mathcal{N}_1\circ\mathcal{N}_2=\mathcal{N}_{B'\rightarrow B}\circ\mathcal{N}_{A\rightarrow B'}$. Here $A$,$B'$ and $B$ refer to the initial system, the intermediate system and the output system.

I was wondering if acomplementary channel to the environment can be obtained by using the complementary channels of the individual channels. My reasoning would be that if we want to obtain complementary channel $\mathcal{N}^c_{A\rightarrow E}$, we can obtain such by the following concatenation:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{N}^c_{A\rightarrow E}=\mathcal{N}^c_{B'\rightarrow E}\circ\mathcal{N}_{A\rightarrow B'}.
\end{equation}

Is this correct? If not, where is the problem in my reasoning and is there any way to get such a complementary channel?